# Would a 3.5 grade in the subject that I want to specialize in have a negative impact on my grad application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states

I'm applying to math PhD programs in the US (I'm also in the US). In my statement of purpose, I write that I want to specialize in probability theory. However, this semester I took a measure-theoretic course in probability theory, and I did not do well on the final exam. This resulted in a 3.5 final grade (at my school, we have 4.0 then 3.5, 3.0, etc).

I worry that getting a 3.5 in the subject that I said I wanted to specialize in would have a negative impact on my application, especially for the top schools. Would it be wise to revise my statement of purpose and replace probability with something else I'm interested in? I'm broadly interested in analysis.

Also, I submitted the transcript that only has the courses I took before the Fall semester, but I they might ask about my Fall grades at some point during the review process (or during an interview).

Thank you!

Edit: added the country

Comment: In what country are you planning to pursue a PhD?

Comment: It is in the US.

Answer (score -1):

In the US, admissions is based on a broad set of criteria. A single course that isn't perfect isn't likely, on its own to be much of an issue. In the final year, it is also common for people to do a bit worse than previously since they have other things going on (like applying to grad school).

However, note that competition can be fierce, especially at top schools. If you don't narrow your search too much then I'd expect you to do OK, though decisions are made by individuals with their own judgements.

Most important, is that you get good letters of recommendation that predict your success in your chosen field.